# Uncaught Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException: Unable to extract timestamp and signatures from header

Tags: fatal-error

I integrated Stripe Checkout to make payments for products and services on my site.

Everything works.

There is only one problem.

I want to validate whether the purchase was made or not and the only way to do it is through the following PHP code:

**page-checkout.php**

```
<?php
require_once('stripe/vendor/autoload.php');

// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_...');

/*-----------------------
Check if user is logged
-----------------------*/
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

/*-----------------------
Recupera data
-----------------------*/
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$user_email = $current_user->user_email;

/*-----------------------
Crea product with plan
-----------------------*/
if ( isset( $_GET['prodotto'] ) && $_GET['prodotto'] == 'mese') {

    $prodotto = \Stripe\Product::retrieve('prod_...');
    $piano = \Stripe\Plan::retrieve('plan_...');

    $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
      'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
      'subscription_data' => [
        'items' => [[
          'plan' => $piano->id,
        ]],
      ],
      'success_url' => '.../dashboard',
      'cancel_url' => '.../processo-checkout/?prodotto=' . $_GET['prodotto'] . '&login=loggato',
    ]);

}

$endpoint_secret = 'whsec_...';

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
$event = null;

try {
  $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
    $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
  );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
  // Invalid payload
  http_response_code(400);
  exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Error\SignatureVerification $e) {
  // Invalid signature
  http_response_code(400);
  exit();
}

// Handle the checkout.session.completed event
if ($event->type == 'checkout.session.completed') {
  $session = $event->data->object;

  // Fulfill the purchase...
  handle_checkout_session($session);
}

http_response_code(200);

/*-----------------------
Conclude check to see if the user is logged in
-----------------------*/
} else {
  wp_redirect( home_url() . '/processo-checkout/?prodotto=' . $_GET['prodotto'] );
  exit();
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
<body id="body" <?php body_class(); ?>>
<main id="contenuto-principale" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/CollectionPage" role="main">

<script type="text/javascript">

var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_...');
var CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID = "<?php echo $session->id; ?>";

stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
  // available to this file, so you can provide it as parameter here
  // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
  sessionId: CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID
}).then(function (result) {
  // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
  // error, display the localized error message to your customer
  // using `result.error.message`.
});
</script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The problem is that I receive the following message when I go to make the purchase:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Stripe Exception SignatureVerificationException:
>   Unable to extract timestamp and signatures from header

How can I solve this problem? I'm looking everywhere on Google but I haven't had any luck.

I also tried to print the $sig_header value and it returns empty.

Thanks to those who will help me!

Comment: “I also tried to print the $sig_header value and it returns empty.“ - that’s the problem then. This is your Stripe webhook handler? You’ll need to work out why Stripe isn’t sending you the Stripe-Signature header. Can you log the complete request? What does it look like?

Comment: Hi Rup, I don't know, it's quite strange. This is Stripe's library regarding this topic: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures

Comment: You can find more information about it here too: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment#webhooks

Comment: Obviously I've already installed everything like the Stripe vendor library at the following link:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php

For the rest, combine everything correctly for the rest. I just need to be able to connect this webhook correctly.

Comment: At the following link you can find the complete error that returns me.

I think the $payload value is also wrong.

https://monosnap.com/file/c3hUwJe5h2rHqJtsg8o0jEEJtKAuD9

Comment: The first link says “Stripe can optionally sign” so it’s worth checking that you’ve definitely turned this on if there is an option. But apart from that I guess you need to ask Stripe why they’re not sending the signature. Does everything else in the webhook work, i.e. if you ignore the signature do you get the correct data posted? What headers do you have?

Comment: I update the question to show you the complete code, thanks for the help you are giving me. It is much appreciated!

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like the body is just ‘submit_loggato=‘ and doesn’t look like a correct post back from Stripe. When you say that’s the error message you’re getting, you’re not calling this code yourself are you? This should be code called by a post back initiated by stripe, not your user. But I don’t think there’s enough information here to debug this: you’ll have to ask Stripe for help I think why they are sending you bad postbacks.

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried to contact the assistance of Stripe but not speaking English well I cannot call them.

The only solution I have is to contact them via email but they do not give any assistance for the development, I have already heard.

Comment: And I’d be surprised if get_current_user works: Stripe won’t have your user’s cookies. This is starting to look like this is on a page your user loads, and I think that’s wrong: the Stripe-Signature will be on a web hook call from Stripe and you’ll have to process that without user information: look up the purchase in your database and mark it successful there, so that you can show that success to your user.

Comment: This is the webhook I created in the Stripe dashboard, do you know if it's okay and if that's where I have to enter a specific payload? https://monosnap.com/file/p1QfVmQ5VFasFv3Uz3uWdybFoIVnb7

Comment: This is a test page:

https://areamembri.martinamarinelli.com/processo-checkout/?prodotto=mese

Can you examine it?

Thus you will surely understand its operation better.

Comment: That looks wrong, yes. It looks like you have set the callback URL to be the home page of your site whereas I’d needs to be the URL of a web service or dummy page that does the Stripe-Signature check.

Comment: As you can see you will land on a page where you can log in or register.

It is necessary to make the purchase.

I don't need the data from wp_get_current_user () on that page.

That is a useless additional code that I was wrong to insert, now I delete it.

Comment: (Although actually using the homepage could work if you set up your theme to check every request for the Stripe-Signature header and treat it as a Stripe callback if it finds it. But I’d guess a REST endpoint would be better.)

Comment: Thanks to your help, I was able to get Stripe to run the webhook. Now if I try to send a test it works correctly.
I inserted the following link: https://areamembri.martinamarinelli.com/processo-checkout/
Where indeed the first interaction by Stripe is requested.

Comment: Now the error seems to have updated when I go to make the payment.

Here it is: https://monosnap.com/file/1USdFJ5Tko6rnZoGTGceEobB5Hwle2